# Substitute or ignore multiple substrings with regex Erlang/Pearl

Tags: regex, erlang

I'm trying to extract substrings from folder-names(music-album-names with release-year) with Erlang-regex. I don't expect it to work for all folder-names but if it works for 90% it would be good enough. I need the name of the album and the year of release. And if there is a year of remastering, I need that also. I basically want to exclude any special-characters such as `-[]()` and strings such as "Remastered, Live, Recorded"

The cases, so far, I want to handle are:

```
 1985-An Album Title                        %return:  1985 An Album Title
 1985-An Album Title (2003 Remastered)      %return:  1985 An Album Title 2003
 An Album Title-1985                        %return:  An Album Title 1985
 An Album Title 1985                        %this should be returned as is 
 An Album Title                             %            "
 1984                                       %            "
 1985 An Album Title                        %            "
```

My attempt first check for a correct year-format but then I'm stuck on the hyphen(-) after "1989". How can I ignore the hyphen or replace it with a blank space?

```
test_regex() ->
  Str = "1989-Dr.Feelgood [2009, 2CD Deluxe Edition]",
  RegEx = "(^(?:19|20)\\d{2})*  <--- What next?              %(?![-])D",              
  case re:run(Str, RegEx, [{capture, first, list}]) of
    {match, Captured} -> io:format("Captured: ~p~n",[Captured]);
    nomatch -> io:format("no match ~n")
 end.
```

There is also a replace-function but I can't figure out how use it properly:

```
test_regex() -> 
  Str = "1989-Dr.Feelgood [2009, 2CD Deluxe Edition]",
  RegEx = "(^(?:19|20)\\d{2})*-.*",
  case re:replace(Str, RegEx, "\s", [{return, list}]) of
    X -> io:format("X ~p ~n",[X])
  end.
```

Comment: Try replacing with `\s*\b(?:Remastered|Live|Recorded)\b|[^\da-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 1):

Erlang (without regex):

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

clean(String) ->
    clean(String, _Result=[]).

clean([$-|T], Result) -> clean(T, [$ |Result]);  %%Replace hyphen with space
clean([H|T], Result) when H==$(;   %%Delete [,],(,)
                          H==$);
                          H==$[;
                          H==$] -> clean(T, Result);
clean([$ ,$R,$e,$m,$a,$s,$t,$e,$r,$e,$d | T], Result) ->
    clean(T, Result);
clean([$ ,$L,$i,$v,$e | T], Result) ->
    clean(T, Result);
clean([$ ,$R,$e,$c,$o,$r,$d,$e,$d | T], Result) ->
    clean(T, Result);
clean([H|T], Result) ->
    clean(T, [H|Result]);
clean([], Result) ->
    lists:reverse(Result).

test() ->
  "1985 An Album Title"      = clean("1985-An Album Title"),
  "1985 An Album Title 2003" = clean("1985-An Album Title (2003 Remastered)"),
  "An Album Title 1985"      = clean("An Album Title-1985"),
  "An Album Title 1985"      = clean("An Album Title 1985"),
  "An Album Title"           = clean("An Album Title"),
  "1984"                     = clean("1984"),
  "1985 An Album Title"      = clean("1985 An Album Title"), 
  ok.
```

In the shell:

```
27> c(a).    
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

28> a:test().
ok
```

Comment: Is this solution faster than using regex?

Comment: @datamoose, Give it a whirl: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html#benchmarking

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl answer:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

sub clean {
    my $str = shift;

    $str =~ tr/-/ /;  #Replace hyphens with spaces
    $str =~ s/        #Delete content inside parenthesis
                \s+
                \( 
                ( [^\)]* )
                \)
            //xms;

    #If parenthetical content found, extract a date:
    my $date = "";
    if(my $parens_content = $1) {
        $parens_content =~ /(\d{4})/xms;
        if ($1) {  #then found a date inside parens_content
            $date = " $1";
        }
    }

    "$str$date";
 }

say clean("1985-An Album Title");
say clean("1985-An Album Title (2003 Remastered)");
say clean("An Album Title-1985");
say clean("An Album Title");
say clean("1984");
say clean("1985 An Album Title");
```

Output:

```
$ perl a.pl
1985 An Album Title
1985 An Album Title 2003
An Album Title 1985
An Album Title
1984
1985 An Album Title
```